# Where to redirect user after Google SAML Sign Out?

Tags: google-apps, single-sign-on, saml

My company uses Google Apps, and we've built a single sign-on application to do our custom authentication.

It's been working just fine for several months.

I've noticed that with certain Google features (like switching accounts), the user is often supposed to get redirected back to a certain web page.

If the user isn't logged into any of our Google Apps accounts, then this works fine. However, if they're logged into one of our Google Apps accounts, then it ends up dead-ending at our sign-out page, because I don't know where I'm supposed to send the user at that point.

We actually don't even use the sign-out page for anything at all, it's only there because it's a required field when setting up SSO for Google Apps.

So my question: Where am I supposed to send the user after they've come to my custom sign-out page?

Answer (score 1):

Where do you send them?  Wherever you want them to be after sign out! :)

There are typically two places you get redirected to after sign out: the company's main page, or the sign in page.

For example, if I built a SSO for the Stanford Med School, after sign out, I'd probably redirect to med.stanford.edu or med.stanford.edu/signin (hypothetical).

In your case, I'd either redirect to your company's main page, or redirect back to your custom sign in page.